# Does Sri Lankan Airlines still offer hotels on long layovers in Colombo? And if so, do they help with visas?

Tags: air-travel, transit, airlines, sri-lanka

I've seen quite a few references to Sri Lankan Airlines offering free hotels for people with an unavoidable 8-24 hour transit layover in Colombo. They all seem to point to http://www.srilankan.com/en-US/flying-with-us/night-stop which alas these days is a 404...

Is Sri Lankan Airlines still offering this program?

And if so, do you need to sort your own Sri Lankan visa out in advance (eg 
[a Sri Lankan ETA](https://www.eta.gov.lk/slvisa/visainfo/center.jsp?locale=en_US)), or does the airline sort that for you in advance if you need one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes

According to an inquiry made to Sri Lankan airlines customer service in March 2016 [posted here](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/26353976-post20.html)

> Dear Sir/Madam
>
> Thank you for contacting SriLankan Airlines.
>
> Refer below criteria to be met in order to be eligible for complimentary >transit hotel accommodation as requested.
>   We regret to inform you that we do not handle visa queries. Please visit >www.eta.gov.lk for more information if required.
>
> 1. The transit time should be over 8 hours and less than 24 hours.
> 2. The net fare paid should be over USD 180(exclusive of taxes) for one->way journeys and over USD 360(exclusive of taxes) for return tickets.
> 3. The connecting flight must be on the first available connection.
> 4. Pakistani passport Holders should obtain ETA.
> 5. Hotel accommodation will only be provided in Colombo.
>
> If you require further clarification, please contact our Call Center on >the numbers below.
>
> Within Sri Lanka – 1979 | From UK - 330 808 0800 | From Singapore - 315 >805 80 | From Germany - 6990 732 333 | From France - 9751 81999 | From >Hong Kong - 819 800 79 | From Japan – 505 532 3229 | From Italy – 0689 >970 268 | From Malaysia – 321 683 615 | From Thailand – 600 035 642 | >From outside Sri Lanka - +94 11777 1979

According to other posts in [the same thread](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/other-asian-australian-south-pacific-airlines/638374-free-hotel-night-stop-services-sri-lankan-airlines.html) they can help with the visa, however they recommend doing it online as it is a relatively fast and easy process.

Comment: @mts updated wit a more recent answer to the question, although still 6 months old.

Comment: removed my comment and +1. To further improve your answer, you could contact Sri Lankan e.g. via FB or Twitter and ask if they still do as of now. Airlines are usually pretty responsive there.

Comment: Based on what they said at the transfer desk this morning, it's possible to contact them in advance to arrange the hotel and confirm the details, which speeds things up on arrival. You also really want get your visa online in advance, the queue for visa-on-arrival was epic!